# ImportError: No module named setuptools

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to import urllib.request on python, but when I try to do so, i get the following error: ImportError: No module named setuptools. 
I tried doing 'sudo apt-get install -y python-setuptools' , but after doing so too I am getting the same error. 
I am using PyCharm and my Python version is Python 2.7.12+.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is any specific requirement to use `urllib`. I suggest you use `python-requests`. Both do the same.